# DataGrid Header styling

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm trying to merge the header cells of multiple columns of my WPF DataGrid, something like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|              Source               |              Destination          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    Name   |   Type   |   Length   |    Name   |   Type   |   Length   |
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
|           |          |            |           |          |            |
|           |          |            |           |          |            |
|           |          |            |           |          |            |
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried using `<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>` but that seems to be restricted to each column individually. What's the easiest way of achieving this? Do I need to modify DataGrid's default template?

Comment: You've got options, you could go edit the datagrid style template(s) accordingly, or you could create what you want with just a templated ItemsControl or HeaderedItemsControl and get the same effect, though if you do it that way you lose the default extra functionality like sorting etc.